# python regix how to split two word and add comma?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

This is my string:

```
Hair ReplacementHair BraidingHair Supplies & Accessories
```

my expected result should be:

```
Hair Replacement,Hair Braiding,Hair Supplies & Accessories
```

If two word like this  `ReplacementHair` I want to split this two word and add comma between theme.

I tried this code:

```
re.sub(r"(\w)([A-Z])", r"\1 \2", text)
```

The above code splitting two word and add space between theme. I want comma instead of space.

Comment: so don't seperate them with a space? put a comma in

Comment: `re.sub(r"(\w)([A-Z])", r"\1,\2", text)` or `re.sub(r"([a-z])([A-Z])", r"\1,\2", text)`

Comment: `re.split('(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])', text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the space in the replacement pattern with a comma.

```
import re
text = "Hair ReplacementHair BraidingHair Supplies & Accessories"
text2 = re.sub(r"(\w)([A-Z])", r"\1,\2", text)
print(text2)
```

output

```
Hair Replacement,Hair Braiding,Hair Supplies & Accessories
```